# PHP CURL PATCH to API creating instead of updating

Tags: php, curl

I am using a client management software called UCRM. The API I am using is meant to patch/update but it seems to make new entries when it comes to the contacts array.

```
            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url.com" . $clientID);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
              \"contacts\": [
                {
                  \"phone\": \"" . $pendingTo . "\"
                }
              ]
            }");

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
              "Content-Type: application/json",
              "X-Auth-App-Key: 12345"
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

I can't figure out how to make it update the existing phone number in the contacts array. The code above seems to add to the array.

Comment: If you run a `GET` request on that `$clientID`, are you getting anything back? Also, your URL should look like this: `"https://ucrm-demo.ubnt.com/api/v1.0/clients/" . $clientID`

Comment: @IcedAnt My URL does look like that, I just removed it for security. When I do a GET on a client ID and echo the result I get this data: https://pastebin.com/5Y5B5CaG

Comment: As there can be many contacts (it's an array), you have to specify for which one you want to update the phone. I'm not sure how you'd do that though...

Comment: @IceAnt Yeah that's where I'm stuck mhmhm.

Comment: The contact id is probably unique, try adding that to your JSON string `{
              \"contacts\": [
                {
                  \"id\": \"23\",
                  \"phone\": \"" . $pendingTo . "\"
                }
              ]
            }`

Comment: @iceAnt I've tried adding that but then it returns saying I'm not allowed to use the "id" field.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [UCRM API Inspector](https://ucrm.docs.apiary.io/traffic).

Apparently, your request is invalid because "street1", "city" and "zipCode" are required:

> At '/street1' Missing required property: street1
>
> At '/city' Missing required property: city
>
> At '/zipCode' Missing required property: zipCode

Try it like this and let me know:

```
{

  "street1": "2580 Orchard Pkwy",

  "city": "San Jose",

  "zipCode": "95131",

  "contacts": [

    {

      "phone": "1234"

    }

  ]

}
```

I would actually advise you to run a `GET` first on the customer you want to update, modify the JSON string that is returned and then `PATCH` it.

Comment: Tried both of those suggestions, still creating another record. mhmh

Answer (score 0):

Just try this, $data id request data you want to update.

```
function patchCURL($url, $data)
{

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

    // execute!
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    // close the connection, release resources used
    curl_close($curl);

    // do anything you want with your response
    return json_decode($response, true);
}
```